# NodeJS giving error while trying to install

Tags: node.js, debugging, mern

I was working on a project,and suddenly Node started acting up.
It gives me error code 1 when I try to install any library.
I googled for this error and found stackoverflow answers for the same,which included some solutions like deleting package-lock.json file,clearing the cache and trying npm install,using verbose method etc.

However,even after using these methods,I am not able to fix my error.
The screenshot attached below shows the error nodejs has when I run the command npm install.
[image]

The entire list of error is very long,and I can send the entire log,in case someone requires it for debugging purpose.

Kindly help me with the issue.

Comment: It's showing the compiler failing during the build of `node-sass`, but not the reason _why_ it's failing. That should probably be somewhere towards the end.

Comment: @robertklep I am relatively new to NodeJS, so can you elaborate a bit on what might be wrong?

Comment: No, because your question isn't showing the reason why the compilation is failing.

Comment: @robertklep How can I find out the reason why compilation is failing?

Comment: Well, like I said: the reason why it's failing is probably located somewhere towards the end of the log. You could add the last 100 or so lines to your question (as text, in a code block, not as an image!)

Comment: https://cl1p.net/error @robertklep This is the entire log, I would appreciate if you could help me out!

Comment: Your project relies on `node-sass@4.3.0`, which cannot be used with the version of Node.js you use (v16). You need to upgrade to (at least) `node-sass@6.0.1`. See the duplicate answer for more details.